# Cannot get ListView selected item attribute

Tags: android, mongodb, listview

I make http request from MongoDB and I successfully display a list I get from my request. Now When I click on ListView item I get user full name, but I cannot get user Id (Mongo ID). How can I do this?

User class:

```
public class User implements Serializable {

private String user_id;
private String name;
private String username;
private String password;

public User( String user_id, String name, String username, String password) {
    this.nom_prenom = nom_prenom;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

public String getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}

public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

In my activity, I put :

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
try {
    JSONObject userJson = data.getJSONObject(i);
    if (userJson.has("_id") && userJson.has("name") && userJson.has("password")
            && userJson.has("username")) {
        JSONObject idJson = userJson.getJSONObject("_id");
        String user_id = idJson.getString("$oid");
        String name = userJson.getString("name");
        String username = userJson.getString("username");
        String password = userJson.getString("password");

        rentalProperties.add(new user(user_id, name, username, password));
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}

//...

FragmentManager fragMgr = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMgr.beginTransaction();

UsersFragment usersFrag = UsersFragment.newInstance(rentalProperties);
fragTrans.replace(R.id.fragment_view, usersFrag, "MY_FRAGMENT");

fragTrans.commit();

mfragment_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

I have also adapter based on "rentalProperties". I get user's name like this:

```
mList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
              User obj = adapter.getItem(position);

              String user_id = (String) obj.getUser_id();

              String name = (String) obj.getName();

              Log.e("User", user_id);

              Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MainDisponibilitesActivity.class);

              intent.putExtra(UserChoosedId, user_id);

              intent.putExtra(UserChoosedName, name);

              startActivity(intent);

}
```

I wish this can explain my situation. I have too many files.
Thanks

Comment: Post your code....

Comment: I solved it, I just forget to add user_id in User class constructor. Sorry. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

If you want get an Id from the list view item (not the list position) you need to add that Id to the model of list view item when that data retrieve from the MongoDB. If you didn't add any Id to the list view item model from the database you haven't any Ids to get when click the list view item.